# Can a PC boot without a GPU of any kind if it is using software rendering?

Tags: boot, bios, gpu, post

Me and my friend were arguing earlier about whether or not it's possible to use a computer (at all) without any kind of GPU, which he thought was impossible. So I told him about software rendering and headless systems, but he said then the system would fail to boot before it could start using the software rendering. I didn't think about that and wasn't sure how to get past that, but I insisted that it was possible because then systems such as servers would not boot, which I would presume many don't have GPUs at all (they would be using a server CPU so no IGPU and they wouldn't need a dedicated GPU probably).

Comment: I don’t know of any functional computer that doesn’t have a way to output data, either via an onboard video adapter or an add on video adapter. Technically, it’s not necessary to have any ability to display video. But, how will you ever prove it will work if there are no servers or workstations created without at least some video capability. It would also be specific to the hardware and software that is being used.

Comment: Your friend is correct. Most *PCs* won’t boot without a graphics card, because the firmware insists one must be there. It’s not strictly a technical reason. Most servers have an onboard GPU.

Comment: @Appleoddity A computer could simply be accessed via SSH (Many server admins do this I believe) and that would be a way to output data. Of course there would have to be a computer somewhere with graphical output to check if the computers are working but I don't want all PCs to be built without GPUs, I'm just wondering if it's possible for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely common - many routers and NAS boxes would qualify as computers even under restricted definitions, and they don't have any GPUs. (But run pretty much any Linux app you care to mension).

A fair number of computing devices have some variant of serial cable which can (optionally) be used to debug a boot process.

Many headless systems can be network booted and loaded with a full OS install, including regular PCs with no onboard or discrete GPU.